# Enterprise controlling Android Accessibility Service "opt-in"

Tags: android, mdm, accessibility-api, airwatch, accessibility

We're developing an Enterprise [accessibility service](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html) that works over AirWatch (an EMM/MDM) and find we can control most Android settings using the MDM, however we can't seem to find a way for the Enterprise to auto-enroll our application into receiving Accessibility events - this instead requires the user to manually opt-in by opening the Accessibility system settings and manually enrolling the application by checking a check box.

The device is owned by the Enterprise, not the user. Our understanding is this is exactly the type of thing MDMs are all about (moving the ownership/control of the device from the user and to the Enterprise), therefore, is there a way to programmatically or centrally auto-enroll our application so it can receive Accessibility events without relying on the users to do this? Our application will be side-loaded onto tens of thousands of devices, some have the settings menu restricted so manual enrolment is not really an option.

[image: opt-in to receive accessibility events example]

If there isn't a way, is this just because Android hasn't added this ability in yet? Can it be done via the Knox SDK? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: The main issue with MDM and Android is that Android itself doesn't provide a MDM API. It is each constructor who develop his own MDM API and they mostly are very light, except for Samsung.

Comment: Android for Enterprise, Android Device Administration API and Application Restrictions are all features built into Android which take the ownership from the device owner to the corporation. Most settings can be centralised via the ADA API except Accessibility

Comment: @tommed you are correct; however things like 'accessibility' are obscure controls not demanded by Enterprises; so only iOS and only in KIOSK mode allows you trigger them.

Comment: @zaitsman I can assure you that accessibility is demanded by most all the federal agencies (large enterprises in my book!), and they are not obscure! Many users without disabilities use them regularly (especially large text).

Comment: I agree, I think Google and the UEM/EMM/MDM suppliers need to accept accessibility as a first-class citizen

Comment: @tommed Did you finally come up with a solution?